# Google Apps Script ask for asking for very broad permissions to access all sheets and too much data. How to limit this

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

Im creating a macro in google sheet which will be used by third parties.

Ive tried inserting this code above my script but its not limiting the very overbearing permissions requests to users.

Any solutions would be super welcome.

I want the script to request access to ONLY this one spreadsheet, so i dont freak out my users.

''''

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 * @NotOnlyCurrentDoc
 * @include currentonly
 * @exclude currentonly
 */
// Configuration for OAuthScopes
var CONFIG = {
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly"
  ]
};
```

''''

Comment: - [Manual authorization scopes for Sheets, Docs, Slides, and Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#manual_authorization_scopes_forand)

Comment: Try this search on this website `[google-apps-script] @OnlyCurrentDoc`

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the specifics of your macro? Are you deploying the macro for users to import on their end, or are they accessing it within a shared spreadsheet? How are you sharing '**that one specific spreadsheet**' with your third-party users, AND what **specific permissions** are causing concern for them?

Comment: Why did you add `@NotOnlyCurrentDoc`?